# Как запретить ввод недопустимых символов и первый недопустимый символ не удалять?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Такая задача:
пользователь начал ввод на русском языке, ошибка появляется после ввода первой буквы, ввод блокируется, введенную букву не удаляем:

```
$('.js-au-email').keyup(function() {
    var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]+$/i;
    if(!regexp.test(this.value)) {
        alert('ошибка в символе')
    }  
    else {

    }

});
```

Подскажите, как дальше запретить ввод, но при этом не блокируя текстовое поле, чтобы дать возможность удалить символ?

Comment: т.к. у Вас поиск регистронезависимый (i), то не `a-zA-Z`, а можно просто `a-z` и если нужно проверять на русские буквы, то `а-я`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```js
var count_error = 0;
$('.js-au-email').on("keyup", function() {
  var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]+$/i;
  if (!regexp.test($(this).val()) && count_error == 0) {
    alert('ошибка в символе');
    count_error = 1;
  } else if (!regexp.test($(this).val()) && count_error == 1 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
    alert('ошибка в символе');
    $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
  } else if ($(this).val().length < 1 || regexp.test($(this).val())) {
    count_error = 0;
  }
console.log(count_error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="js-au-email" class="js-au-email">
```

**UPD:** добавлена проверка на пустое значение, чтобы `alert` не всплывал при удалении последнего символа в строке не подходящего по шаблону.

**Вариант 2:** если не спешить можно упростить:

```js
$('.js-au-email').on("keyup", function() {
  if (($(this).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]/g)||[]).length == 1) {
    alert('ошибка в символе');
  } else if(($(this).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]/g)||[]).length > 1){
    alert('ошибка в символе');
    $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="js-au-email" class="js-au-email">
```

**Вариант 2.1:** если нужно запретить ввод, в т.ч. правильных символов, после введенного неправильного символа:

```js
$('.js-au-email').on("keyup", function() {
  if (($(this).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]/g)||[]).length == 1) {
    alert('ошибка в символе');
    if ($(this).val().length > 1 &&
      ($(this).val().substr(-1).match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]/g) || []).length < 1) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
    }
  } else if(($(this).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]/g)||[]).length > 1){
    alert('ошибка в символе');
    $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="js-au-email" class="js-au-email">
```

Comment: ах если бы если бы

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов Вам нужно сохранять первый ошибочный символ?

Comment: Да верно, но у вашего когда ничего не работает, т.е. даже символы относящиеся к регулярке не дают ничего ввести

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов обновили ответ, сейчас первый ошибочный символ сохраняется, второй удаляется

Comment: @Alex http://joxi.ru/LmGMveguRWjbaA опять мимо :) если нажать на следующую кнопку сразу же можно продолжать вводить текст после каждого алерта

Comment: @Peresada на скорую руку) сейчас обновим

Comment: @Peresada обновили, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Все круто! Благодарю вас! Станьте моим учителем:-)

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов если Вам подошло решение в ответе, отметьте его как решение, для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа, галка станет зеленой - это будет означать, то данный ответ является решением Вашего вопрос. P.S.: обратите внимание, что ответ обновлен.

Comment: С удовольствием бы, но Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов Вы не на ту галку видимо нажимаете, галка должна быть в данном поле http://prntscr.com/irjbph (сейчас она серая)

Comment: Все теперь понял :-)

Comment: @Alex подскажите пожалуйста еще такой момент, после ввода символа который не проходит валидацию можно вводить символы в условии, например в3333

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов извините непонятно. вы имеете ввиду как такое сделать (разрешить ввод символов) ?

Comment: После ввода запрещенного символа, запретить ввод полностью, сейчас же можно написать запрещенный символ и продолжить ввод разрешенных

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов ответ обновлен, см. вариант 2.1